# Calling Function of one class from another class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, containers

I have one view controller and it contains two Containers. First Container is embedded with FirstViewController which has 2 buttons  and second Container is embedded with PreviewViewController which has webview. I want to load pdf in that Webview. I have taken outlet of webview. on ViewDidLoad Webview is hidden. Now I want that If I clicked on any button that webview sholud be shown and I click Button1 webview should load PDF named 1 and by clicking on Button2 webview should load PDF named 2.

Now I don't know to do this!! This is my code. It is giving me an error of

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on Line `webview.hidden = true` in the code which is given below. This is written in `PreviewViewController`.

```
@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!

func showpdf(id : Int)
    {
        webview.hidden = false

        if id == 1
        {
            if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("1", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
                let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
                // let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(30,30,self.view.frame.size.width-250,self.view.frame.size.height-250))
                webview.loadRequest(req)
                self.view.addSubview(webview)
            }
        }
        else if id == 2
        {
            if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("2", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
                let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
                webview.loadRequest(req)
                self.view.addSubview(webview)
            }
        }        
    }
```

Now, I am calling this Function from FirstViewController on buttonclick.

```
PreviewViewController().showpdf(1)
```

But app crashes by giving error given above. Can anyone Suggest me how can I solve this?

**EDIT:**
 I am calling it on button click of FirstViewController's Button Click.

```
@IBAction func btnSave(sender: UIButton) {

       PreviewViewController().showpdf(5)
 }
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have several view controllers inside a view controller?

Comment: I have Two Containers inside main Controller.. and Two Containers are embeded with two ViewControllers @ Tim Vermeulen

Comment: You have to call to PreviewViewController instance, not to its class..  give us bit more code where and how you use PreviewViewController

Comment: @RiddhiShah Why don't you just add these "containers" to the original view controller? There's no need to have a separate controller for everything.

Comment: Actually I want a view like this..(as shown in image..) for iPad. So I have used two Containers. When I Click on personal Details(assuming now as button) It shold open pdf in another container @ Tim Vermeulen

Comment: I saw similar questions already. The answer can only be, read or watch a tutorial about delegation and MVC in iOS.

Comment: Ok sir.. Thanks. I have searched about this. and tried many things. but I am not getting.. that's I asked this question.@  Daniele Bernardini

Answer (score 0):

Before I explain one possible solution to your problem, I strongly advise you to go through a complete course on iOS MVC, it might take a few days but you will be able to get around this kind of problem easily on your own. There is one available for iOS8 by Prof. Hegarty from Stanford on the internet. Although swift has changed from what it was in iOS 8 the MVC architecture did not change.

What you need is to create a *protocol* to use as delegate for the action of pressing the two buttons, lets call it `PDFProtocol`. This protocol should have 1 method, for example `showPDF(id:String)`

Your main view controller should implement `PDFProtocol`. Now the main view controller in the prepare for segue should set itself as pdfDelegate for the first view controller and it should keep a pointer to the preview view controller Like this:

```
if let t = targetViewController as? FirstViewController {
    t.pdfDelegate = self
} else if let t = targetViewController as? PreviewViewController {
    self.previewViewController = t
}
```

The first view controller should have a variable for the pdfDelegate:

```
var pdfDelegate: PDFProtocol?
```

and when you press the button should call the appropriate action on the delegate like this:

```
guard delegate = pdfDelegate else {
    AssertFail("no delegate found")
    return
}
delegate.showPDF("myfirstpdf")
```

The main view controller should then implement the `showPDF(id:String)`method as follows:

```
func showPDF(id:string) {
    self.previewViewController.showPDF(id)
}
```

And that's it. I typed the code directly in here without trying to compile it, so beware of typos!

Comment: I tried as you told me.. but don't know where I m doing wrong. @Daniele Bernardini

Comment: I cant help you if you do not give me more details. Debug your code, see if your variables are set and if your functions are called.

Comment: that goes a bit beyond my commitment :-) check this out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask